# TTL at ElasticsearchRepository

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, ttl

i use Elasticsearch to store some data.
and i want that this data will be auto deleted after 30 days.
also i use ElasticsearchRepository to work with Elasticsearch.
there is option to use TTL at spring ElasticsearchRepository ?

Answer (score 0):

No, Elasticsearch does not have ttl per document. You should use [index lifecycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) for this.